# Directly download file with a url in angular 8 app with .net core similar to asp.net filepath with application url

Tags: angular, file, asp.net-core, url, download

we have a old asp.net application to download the documents. The document links are composed of application url + file path. The link has been shared with multiple applications. the url like - http://aplication.com/filepath/filename.doc
We have migrated the application to .net core and angular 8. We want to use same link to download documents we have given the same url to the new app.but it's not working. any idea how to fix this as it's really critical.

Answer (score 0):

The url won't work since http://application.com would be pointing to the angular app and http://aplication.com/filepath/filename.doc might be tried to resolve as an angular route. A solution would be to host your static files under a subdomain or cdn and use its url for downloading.

http://subdomain.aplication.com/filepath/filename.doc